# Where in the manga does the Berserk (1997) anime end?

Tags: berserk

I have watched the anime *Berserk* and I want to know from which chapter should I continue reading the manga to pick up where the anime left off.

Are there any differences in the plot in anime and manga that I should know about?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> *I want to know from which chapter should I continue reading the manga to pick up where the anime left off.*

The anime ends with Guts having lost his right eye and Casca being thrown aside after being sexually assaulted by Femto. After a complete blank scene, a new scene showed up where Guts left Godo's house.

> This last part didn't occur in the same fashion as in the manga. One must be baffled and would want to know how Guts actually survived the eclipse and managed to meet Godo again. Besides, considering the last scene with Femto, one should start reading manga from **Episode 88: Escape** to know how Guts survived.

---

> *Are there any differences in the plot in anime and manga that I should know about?*

Yes, there are some.

1. In episode 1 of the anime, the girl inadvertently rescued by Guts in the bar was an elf in manga, who followed him later almost everywhere in the story.
2. Certain characters like Skull Knight, Wyald, Apostle Count, Bakiraka Clan *et al*, were omitted from the anime.
3. Certain scenes were also omitted from, as well as added into the anime.

Comment: You can hide the spoilery parts of your answer by putting `>!` at the beginning of each paragraph that you want hidden. I did that for one of your paragraphs; feel free to edit if you think different parts ought to be spoilered.