# Where to continue after Berserk's movies?

Tags: berserk

A while back I have watched all three of the Berserk [movies](http://berserk.wikia.com/wiki/Berserk_(Films)). Since I really enjoyed them, I decided to start watching the anime as well.

The anime, however, starts a while after the events in the movies since Guts already has his mark. Reading the [Berserk wiki](http://berserk.wikia.com/wiki/Berserk_(Anime)), it states that a lot of events are missing in the anime.

Now, since I especially care about Berserk's storyline, I was wondering if I should start watching the anime from start to end, jump in a few episodes of the anime to get the chronological order right, or skip the anime all together and just read the manga?

Comment: Related: http://anime.stackexchange.com/questions/18397/how-to-start-the-berserk-manga-should-i-bother-with-chapters-000a-and-000b, http://anime.stackexchange.com/questions/7335/how-much-of-the-berserk-storyline-do-the-anime-and-ova-cover and http://anime.stackexchange.com/questions/6913/where-in-the-manga-does-the-anime-end.

Comment: If you're interested, there's a [fan-made project](https://vimeo.com/album/2610343) that combines footage from both the anime and the movies into a four part package that delivers as close to the full story as possible. There's quite a lot of stuff in the story that neither the anime or the movies included, so once you watch them, it's recommended that you delve into the manga from the beginning.

Comment: @ʞɹɐzǝɹ Great, I shall look into that this afternoon.